# Data connection is disconnected while talking with phone

Tags: 8.0-oreo, data-connection

I see that my Samsung A5 running Android 8 drops data connection when I am talking with the phone app.

I mean, while data connection is ON and I see 4G icon, by placing a call or answering a phone call, the data connection is lost. After the call ends, I see that it goes back to normal state.

Is that normal?

Comment: That is the normal behavior if **Voice over LTE** (VoLTE) is not active. It has to be supported by the device (and it has to be active) as well as your mobile network provider (and it has to be enabled in your data plan as well).

Comment: Yes that's normal. Voice calls and text messages are preferably sent over GSM (3G/2G) while data operates over 4G. The phenomenon is called Circuit Switched FallBack
(CSFB). MNOs usually don't invest much in VoLTE, an all-in-one 4G solution.

Comment: I can not find Voice over LTE in the phone settings. Either phone or data settings from provider doesn't support that :( Thanks.